# Can I use CKRecord’s field content as localization key when using CKSubscription to send notifications?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

From [alertLocalizationKey - Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/cksubscription/notificationinfo/1514968-alertlocalizationkey):

> Set this property’s value to have the system display a localized string when it receives the corresponding push notification. The system uses the key to find the matching string in your app’s Localizable.string file. If you specify a value for this property, CloudKit ignores the  [alertBody](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/cksubscription/notificationinfo/1515270-alertbody)  property’s value.

Say one of my `CKRecord`’s field is `documentType`, whose contents are enums like `TEXT_FILE`, `IMAGE_FILE`.

In my `Localizable.strings` there are rows like ``` "TEXT_FILE": "Plain Text";``"IMAGE_FILE": "图片"; ```.

So CloudKit stores my app’s localization key rather than the content.

If I set `alertLocalizationKey`  to  `%1$@` and `alertLocalizationArgs`  to  `["documentType"]`, I got notifications like `TEXT_FILE` or `IMAGE_FILE` which are definitely not what I want.

How can I localized notifications in such case? I don’t want to store localizations in CKRecord.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I chose to add a field for localized title in the CKRecord. It's the best solution for my case. But maybe you can utilize [Notification Service Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications).

A simple tip which I learned in a really hard way: you may want to restart your iPhone to get the extension working.